# I'm trying to delete an element from an array

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to delete an element from an array by accepting the array as well as the element to be deleted. But when I print the array, the element prev to the element to be deleted is being displayed. How can I correct this?

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class delete {
    void main() throws Exception {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("Enter the number of numbers");
        int n = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        int x[] = new int[n];
        System.out.println("Enter the numbers");
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            x[i] = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        }
        System.out.println("Enter the number you want to delete");
        int d = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        boolean b;
        int i = 0;
        for (; i < n; i++) {
            if (x[i] == d) {
                b = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        int q = i;//index position of the element to be deleted

        int x2[] = new int[n - 1];
        for (int k = 0; k < n - 1; k++) {
            if (q != k)
                x2[k] = x[k];
            if (q == k)
                x2[k] = x[k + 1];
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < n - 1; j++) {
            System.out.println(x2[j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Look at the loop `for (int k = 0; k < n - 1; k++)`. Here you're using the index `k` if it is not equal to `q` and `k+1`, then it is. But what is on the next iteration? `k` is again not equal to `q`, but you're writing the same value to the array as before, where you used `k+1`. So this is not able to  write the values "_behind_" `q` correctly.

Comment: Giving your variables clear names would make it much easier to follow what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Tom could you be a bit more clear? how do i rectify it?

Comment: An easy fix would be a single loop which writes every value on an index < `q` and then another loop which writes every index > `q`. Then you can avoid the `if` statements in the `for (int k = 0; k < n - 1; k++)` loop.

Comment: @Tom thank you!! that fixed it :)

Comment: Feel free to write an answer for your question with the fixed loops, so other readers with a similar question can see how you've fixed it.

Comment: No, I mean, write an answer, not edit your question ;). How should someone know what your question was, then the code is already fixed?

Comment: Please mind that I rolled back your last edit. This is a Q&A page, which means solutions belong into an answer, not into the question. I extracted your changes into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problematic snippet in OPs code is:

```
for (int k = 0; k < n - 1; k++) {
    if (q != k)
        x2[k] = x[k];
    if (q == k)
        x2[k] = x[k + 1];
}
```

As said in my first comment, this is not able to correctly write each value behind `q` into the new array.

Let's assume the following variables:

```
int n = 9;
int q = 5;
int[] x = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
int[] x2 = new int[n - 1];
```

After running the mentioned loop, `x2` will then be `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 7, 8]`, because in `if (q == k)` OP writes the value of the following index, if it reaches the ignored index and on the next iteration it writes the excact same index again with `if (q != k) x2[k] = x[k];`. That is why "7" occurs twice.

An easy way to fix this is using two separates loops, like OP has done after my suggestion:

```
for (int k = 0; k < q; k++) {
    x2[k] = x[k];
}
for (int k = q; k < n - 1; k++) {
    x2[k] = x[k+1];
}
```

The first loop writes each value before the ignored index and the second loop writes each value behind the ignored index.